# How to use Cmake to build binaries with NASM

Tags: assembly, cmake, nasm

I'm learning x64 and I hate make, so I'm trying to get cmake to build binaries with NASM.

This is roughly supported by cmake but the documentation is crap. This is what I have working right now by cobbling together stuff from stack overflow and then cutting out everything that doesn't break the build:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_LINK_EXECUTABLE "ld <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT elf64)

project(test_project ASM_NASM)

set_source_files_properties(test.s PROPERTIES LANGUAGE ASM_NASM)
add_executable(test test.s)
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    target_compile_options(test PRIVATE -g -Fdwarf)
endif()
```

So a few questions, why do I have to tell cmake to use `ld` to link and is there a better way to do it?

Is there something along the lines of `target_object_format` I can use to specify the object format instead of setting it globally?

Is there a way to make cmake recognize a new extension instead of specifically telling it each file is ASM_NASM?

Comment: Note that nasm source files have the file extension `.asm`, not `.s`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Update: March 13th 2024

[Five years later I landed a CMake patch that fixes most of this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/9306/diffs)

So in CMake versions >= 3.30, the only relevant part of the answer is changing the source file extension via `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS`, which you should probably do via `-D` not via a `set()` command.

The linker and object format should "just work" now.

---

#### Original Answer

Looking at the source, ASM builds are controlled only by [this set of poorly documented environment variables](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Auxiliary/vim/syntax/cmake.vim#L543-601).

[Michael correctly pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56424311/1201456) that by default, `CMAKE_ASM_LINK_EXECUTABLE` is defined to:

```
<CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER> <FLAGS> <CMAKE_ASM_NASM_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>
```

This feels like a bug, since `nasm` doesn't do linking and it's not documented that you need to change this environment variable. So to use `ld` we need to set:

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_LINK_EXECUTABLE "ld <CMAKE_ASM_NASM_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS>  -o <TARGET> <LINK_LIBRARIES>")
```

Next up is the source file extensions, by default [cmake only recognizes `.asm` and `.nasm`](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeASM_NASMInformation.cmake#L7). If we want to extend this, we can do so by using the associated environment variable:

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS ${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS} s S)
```

Lastly the object format, unfortunately this too is [controlled by an environment variable](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeASM_NASMInformation.cmake#L9-33), so we can either change it globally by using:

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT elf64)
```

Or we can get more fine grained control by redefining `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILE_OBJECT` and creating our own property (I don't understand why this isn't done by cmake on its own):

```
enable_language(ASM_NASM)
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILE_OBJECT "<CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILER> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o <OBJECT> <SOURCE>")

# Create a compile option that operates on ASM_NASM files
# If the target has a property NASM_OBJ_FORMAT, use it, otherwise
# use the environment variable CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT
add_compile_options(
    "$<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:ASM_NASM>:-f $<IF:$<BOOL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:NASM_OBJ_FORMAT>>, \
    $<TARGET_PROPERTY:NASM_OBJ_FORMAT>, ${CMAKE_ASM_NASM_OBJECT_FORMAT}>>"
)


add_executable(test test.S)
set_target_properties(test PROPERTIES NASM_OBJ_FORMAT elf64)
```

Prior to cmake 3.15, everytime you enable `ASM_NASM` through `enable_language()` or `project()` you'll overwrite `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_COMPILE_OBJECT`. In versions >3.15 the `enable_language()` call isn't necessary and the language can be enabled normally in `project()`.

Bonus, `CMAKE_ASM_NASM_FLAGS_DEBUG` is empty by default so feel free to set it to something sane:

```
set(CMAKE_ASM_NASM_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g -Fdwarf")
```

Honestly, the ASM support in cmake seems half-baked. It's clearly better than Make or Automake, but doesn't support the idioms of "modern" cmake as smoothly as you would like.

Answer (score 1):

CMake defaults to trying to use the compiler (in this case `nasm`) as the linker. Obviously `nasm` doesn't know anything about linking, so you have to override that setting by specifying which linker to use for your `ASM_NASM` language.

As for specifying the language for your source files, you could do something like this:

```
set(SOURCE_FILES test.s foo.s bar.s)  # etc for all source files
set_source_files_properties(${SOURCE_FILES) PROPERTIES LANGUAGE ASM_NASM)
add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

That way you only have to list all the files once.